Installing SceneBuilder on my Mac, but I can't find the executable file
I am following Bro Code's guide on how to install SceneBuilder with Eclipse and I am stuck because I can't locate the executable file of the SceneBuilder on Finder.
I have actually proceeded with this step before by randomly chosing the SceneBuilder application in Finder as the location, but it didn't seem right since my Eclipse would have so many errors compared to Bro Code's video, so I am repeating the process again because I don't want any complications in the future since I am doing this for my final project.
Has anyone installed SceneBuilder on a Mac before with Eclipse as their IDE? How did you do it?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
